# how to use pandas function with condition, here are using .explode as example

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, pandas-explode

My df:

```
C1     C2       C3
 A   True  [a,b,c]
 A  False  [a,b,c]
 B   True  [a,b,c]
 B  False  [a,b,c]
```

What I want is, only apply `.explode` on `C3` when `C1 == A and C2 == True`. How can I get to my expected result:

```
C1     C2       C3
 A   True        a
 A   True        b
 A   True        c
 A  False  [a,b,c]
 B   True  [a,b,c]
 B  False  [a,b,c]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the rows to be exploded and concat it with other rows.

```py
m = df['C2'] & df['C1'].eq('A')

out = pd.concat([df[m].explode(['C3']), df[~m]])
```

```
print(out)

  C1     C2         C3
0  A   True          a
0  A   True          b
0  A   True          c
1  A  False  [a, b, c]
2  B   True  [a, b, c]
3  B  False  [a, b, c]
```

Since we select the rows to be exploded first, if you want to keep the original order, you can

```py
out = (pd.concat([df[m].explode(['C3']), df[~m]])
       .sort_index()
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
print(df)
  C1     C2             C3
0  A   True  ['a','b','c']
1  A  False  ['a','b','c']
2  B   True  ['a','b','c']
3  B  False  ['a','b','c']
4  A   True  ['a','b','c']

print(out)
  C1     C2         C3
0  A   True          a
1  A   True          b
2  A   True          c
3  A  False  [a, b, c]
4  B   True  [a, b, c]
5  B  False  [a, b, c]
6  A   True          a
7  A   True          b
8  A   True          c
```

If you don't care about the order

```py
out = pd.concat([df[m].explode(['C3']), df[~m]], ignore_index=True)
```

```
print(out)

  C1     C2         C3
0  A   True          a
1  A   True          b
2  A   True          c
3  A   True          a
4  A   True          b
5  A   True          c
6  A  False  [a, b, c]
7  B   True  [a, b, c]
8  B  False  [a, b, c]
```

Comment: ignore_index=True should be added.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks, but I guess it depends on what OP wants the final output looks like. If he wants the order like the original, `.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)` is needed, otherwise, `ignore_index=True` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, you can mask the values that don't find the criteria (with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)), [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
m = df['C2'] & df['C1'].eq('A')
out = df.where(m).explode('C3').combine_first(df)
```

Or, probably more efficient but less concise:

```
out = df.assign(C3=df['C3'].where(m)).explode('C3').fillna({'C3': df['C3']})
```

output:

```
  C1     C2         C3
0  A   True          a
0  A   True          b
0  A   True          c
1  A  False  [a, b, c]
2  B   True  [a, b, c]
3  B  False  [a, b, c]
```